# Unable to see blob data in CQLSH

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

While querying the byte array column of a cassandra table, instead of displaying the byte representation, CQLSH trying to decode the value and giving below error:

```
Failed to format value
'\x8eV4\xfe}\xd9p5\xb3Q\xf8\x87\xc1v3\xe7x!\x00\xd5\xaa>' 
: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Python version: 2.7.14 and CQL Version: 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in ccm (OS X)

I used ~/.ccm/repository/gitCOLONcassandra-3.11/bin/cqlsh instead of ~/.ccm//node1/bin/cqlsh or /usr/local/bin/cqlsh (installed via pip or something).

Another possible solution is to use --encoding=utf8 option.